# AutoFixture vs NBuilder

Tags: .net, mocking, tdd, test-data

I'm selecting tool for populating my .net models (poco) with test data. I'm actually mocking wcf services and need to populate datacontract objects with test data. Found a huge number of test data generation tools, but the majority is related to DB test data generation and don't fit well for .net objects creation.

The most applicable that I found are:

1. [AutoFixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture)
2. [NBuilder](http://www.nbuilder.org)

They both seem to provide quite similar functionality. I'm interested in any feedback on those tools. Pros and cons?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Hi I was in the process of creating my own test builder when I ran into these two.
I have tried both and found autofixture to be far preferable it has a richer syntax is extremely flexible and was easier to modify for my own use.

Marks tests are excellent, well written and this mixed with his [blog](http://blog.ploeh.dk/) should get you most of the way there.

brett